# How to replace FK from table A with the corresponding values in table B?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Table "**Teams**"

| TEAM ID | TEAMNAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NAME-1 |
| 2 | NAME-2 |
| 3 | NAME-3 |
| ... | ... |

Table "**GameScores**"

| GameID | HomeTeam(FK) | AwayTeam(FK) | HomeTeamScore | AwayTeamScore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 30 | 20 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 35 | 30 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 40 | 30 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 50 | 60 |

I want to join the two tables so I get the following table:

| GameID | HomeTeam(FK) | AwayTeam(FK) | HomeTeamScore | AwayTeamScore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NAME-1 | NAME-2 | 30 | 20 |
| 2 | NAME-2 | NAME-3 | 35 | 30 |
| 3 | NAME-3 | NAME-4 | 40 | 30 |
| 4 | NAME-4 | NAME-5 | 50 | 60 |

Just to be clear, the goal is to replace the FK with their corresponding values (team names) from table Teams and also to retain table B column names. I've tried a lot of variations of the following, but it doesn't quite work:

```
SELECT
[GameScores].[GameID],
[Teams].[TeamName],
[Teams].[TeamName],
[GameScores].[HomeTeamScore],
[GameScores].[AwayTeamScore]

FROM [GameScores]
INNER JOIN [Teams] ON [GameScores].[HomeTeam]=[Teams].[TeamID]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joining the table Teams twice with a different alias each time

```
SELECT GameScores.GameID
    ,TeamH.TeamName
    ,TeamA.TeamName
    ,GameScores.HomeTeamScore
    ,GameScores.AwayTeamScore
FROM GameScores 
    INNER JOIN Teams TeamH ON GameScores.HomeTeam=TeamH.TeamID
    INNER JOIN Teams TeamA ON GameScores.AwayTeam=TeamA.TeamID
```

Comment: It should have been HomeTeam and AwayTeam, you can change it. It is just an alias, but did you get the logic, right?

Comment: Yes, I did. I was just not familiar with that syntax but management studio has tooltips that cleared it up for me. Thanks again for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use SQL Server but something like generally works on most SQL platforms

```
SELECT GameScores.GameID, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, HomeTeamScore, AwayTeamScore
FROM (SELECT GameID, TeamID AS HomeTeam FROM GameScores 
      INNER JOIN Teams ON HomeTeam(FK)=TeamID), 
     (SELECT GameID, TeamID as AwayTeam FROM GameScores 
      INNER JOIN Teams ON AwayTeam(FK)=TeamID), 
     GameScores
```